# How many clients can be connected to a WiFi Hotspot?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I want to create an application which hosts a sever in my phone and many people can use it after connecting to my wifi hotspot.

Suppose I want to implement it in a classroom with 50+ students, is it feasible?

I want to know how many clients can be connected to the wifi hotspot. Are there any limitations?

Comment: It's just another Q&A with no sources, but this would seem to indicate that it's not possible to connect that many devices - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680293/can-we-connect-more-than-10-devices-with-wi-fi-hot-spot-in-android

Comment: If you search for [android wifi hotspot maximum connections](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=android%20wifi%20hotspot%20maximum%20connections), most of the results mention 5, 8, 10,.. but nothing close to 50. The issue seems related to hardware capability, including overheating due to too much activity.

Comment: The "normal" wifi hotspots limit it at least to 253 connections by using an IP-address like 192.168.43.x. So far I haven't seen one using 172.16.x or 10.x addresses.

Comment: The software limit seems to originate from the /data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf file which is generated by the system based on /system/etc/hostapd/hostapd_default.conf. Most phones have hard limits of 8 or 10 devices, yet some of them don't seem to have a limit built in. Your milage may vary depending on the device you're using.

Answer (score 6):

**Note:** Partial answer regarding no. of hotspot connections that can be connected to a device.

---

Google on the page "[Set up tethering or portable Wi-Fi hotspot](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2812516?hl=en)" has stated:

> If your device has mobile data, you can turn it into a portable Wi-Fi hotspot for up to 10 other devices, like laptop computers[.]

See also,

> These features depend on your mobile device and your carrier. You may be charged extra for tethering or Wi-Fi hotspot connections. If you have issues, check with your carrier to see whether tethering can be enabled.

As *Andrew* already mentioned in the comment, the results on web usually tells the limit to 5,6,8,10, but not more than 10.

---

I could not find any content that states that hotspot could connect more than 10 devices. One person mentioned(I asked) a limitation vaguely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680293/can-we-connect-more-than-10-devices-with-wi-fi-hot-spot-in-android)(in the comments).

IMO, you can't connect more than 10 devices, not without a hack. And to hack, you need to know why you can't connect more than 10 devices?

---

<sup>Please, do ping here if you(reader) come to know the reason.</sup>

Comment: For rooted devices, od you know how to increase this limit? Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry. I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

To use hotspot in the house with more than 10 devices, I found something that works with a little money. What I end up using were some old devices that I had laying around the house. What you need are two items: a repeater, and also an old router.

If you have to use a repeater alone, use it in bridge mode so it will not be assigning new IP addresses. The IP address is assigned by the phone in that case, so you will reach its limit. On top of that, the repeater itself will take away one of the spots on your phone as one of the 10 devices.

But what I did is the following: I use the repeater which has an ethernet out and connected my phone to the repeater. Then I plugged in my old router into the repeater routers WAN port and connected it with a CAT5 cable to the repeater.   Placed the old router into DHCP mode bring it with a new network name.  Then I connected all the devices to the old router, and none of them show up on the repeater or on the phone's hotspot.

Basically you're creating a subnet I guess. Works great and honestly, for low bandwidth devices, it runs fine. The speed test was almost the same as off of the repeater itself. If anything, use the high priority/bandwidth devices onto the hotspot directly, and then use the repeater/router for the low bandwidth stuff (smart speakers/plugs/lights)

Also another tip I can say, right now my wireless carrier gives me an unlimited hotspot to all of my phones. I have multiple phones that come in and out of the house. So what I have done is to place all the phones with the same exact SSID for the hotspot, and also the same exact password. Therefore, the Wi-Fi repeater will join whichever phone is in the house.  Personally, this has been a great replacement for the internet in my house since my demand for the internet is not that high. And if you have unlimited internet, I guess you can use this even as a replacement for home internet. Also, this way it distributes the Hotspot data usage to all the different phones.

Answer (score -2):

There can only be a 5 clients at a time on a Wi-Fi hotspot.

Comment: Supportable statement through documentation? Please supply a link.

Comment: What? My phone (a Micromax A350 running Android 4.4.2) says I can have 8 clients connected simultaneously to my hotspot.

Answer (score -2):

if you are using 3g then you provide wifi for 5 connections and if you are using 4g then 10 clients can use hotspot.

Comment: Can you provide a source? Is this device dependent? Will one answer confidently work for all?

Comment: and what if you don't have a mobile data connection at all?