# Unlocked Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra's hotspot is only limited to 1 connection

Tags: wifi-hotspot, samsung-galaxy-s-20

My wife and I just switched to Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultras (unlocked and purchased from Samsung.com) from Pixel 3 & 4 XL.  We had no problem with having multiple connections on either device.  On the S20s, under the Mobile Hotspot settings, it says

> Turn your phone into a Wi-Fi access point.  Up to **1** other device will be able to use your phone's mobile data or Wi-Fi connection to access the internet.

Doing some research and talking to Samsung support, there is supposed to be an option in "Configure Mobile Hotspot" to set the maximum number of connections.  This option is not there for us.

I tried a handful of 3rd party hotspot apps and none of them worked. I also tried a few hidden settings apps and I couldn't find anything about setting the maximum connections.

Is there another way of setting this hidden maximum number of connection settings?

Comment: Did you buy carrier-locked phones?  If so, this setting is most likely limited by your carrier.  If you got your Pixel devices through Google Play (or straight from Google) then they would not be subject to this restriction.

Comment: Thanks CzarMatt, I forgot to mention that they are unlocked purchased straight from Samsung in the description.  I did a factory reset on the phone while the SIM was removed and the setting wasn't any different. :(

Comment: Strange.  My friend's Note 10+ says it can connect up to 8 devices.  You might find some information here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96458/how-many-clients-can-be-connected-to-a-wifi-hotspot  My guess is the carrier or settings of your phone are restricting the number somehow.  Try checking battery saver, data saver, any other throttling setting you can think of and play around with the settings.