# Hotspot limit for number of connections?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I play Pokemon Go and have some phones that need to connect to a phone for its Hotspot for Internet.

I found that iPhone / iOS can serve as a hotspot, but has a limit of up to 5 connections for Hotspot.  Is there a limit for Android phones acting as a hotspot?  I have a Samsung A32, OnePlus Nord, and some Xiaomi phones such as 11i and 11 Lite 5G.

Comment: The same question has been asked 6 years ago: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96458/how-many-clients-can-be-connected-to-a-wifi-hotspot There may be devices that allow more than 10 devices, but that seem to be manufacturer specific. Therefore in the end you will have to try it out yourself.